# What does this Big-O notation mean based on appendix?

Tags: terminology, notation

I am reading the following book: **Introduction to Modern Cryptography** Second Edition by Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell.

I am going through **page 533** where they list what some of the notation means, and I came across the following:

> $O(·)$, $Θ(·)$, $Ω(·)$, $ω(·)$ see Appendix A.2

I believe the first symbol is the Big-O notation, but what are the other symbols called? Do they all do the same thing?

I found **Appendix A.2** mentioned above on **page 537** which says:

> PROPOSITION A.2 For all $x ≥ 1$ it holds that $(1 − 1/x)^x ≤ e^{−1}$.

However, I have no idea what this appendix definition is trying to say. I could not even begin to guess as I do not know what the **e** is. Could someone please explain this to me? I am very new to both maths and cryptography.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ol2JbwoJp0) explained things well, especially the second post on the video. However, it did not cover what Big-W does, or even what the "W" symbol is called.

Comment: f(x) = Ω(g(x)) if there exists x0,c s.t. for all x>x0 cg(x)<f(x). f(x) = Θ(g(x)) if f(x) = O(g(x)) and f(x) = Ω(g(x)) So for O,Ω,Θ you can check for more details [here](https://medium.com/@mntknwr/what-is-asymptotic-notation-types-of-asymptotic-notations-9be3e0e5a2ab) Also ω,o are same as O,Ω but with equality

Comment: [cs 1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57/94479) [cs 2](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/846/94479)

Comment: This [video][1] explained things well, especially the second post on the video. However, it did not cover what Big-W does, or even what the "W" symbol is called.


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ol2JbwoJp0

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa What does Big-W do?

Comment: As far as I could find some sources refer to Ω as W.eg. [1](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~burmeste/slideshow/chapter2/2-4.html),[2](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~plaisted/comp550/02-asymp.ppt)

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa Does the W have a special name, probably something Greek?

Comment: it is Capital omega for Ω

Answer (score 2):

In general these definitions are similar everywhere and you can find a definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations).

Also, there is some silly confusion here. You are looking at the wrong thing! You are looking at "Proposition A.2" but you need Chapter/Section A.2 right below.
[image]

Comment: Could you turn those images into MathJax?

Comment: I really appreciate that your post. Would you mind updating it with a simple example of each one, with some small numbers? I am reading through the links posted in this article but I am not exactly smart.

Comment: This [video][1] explained things well, especially the second post on the video. However, it did not cover what Big-W does, or even what the "W" symbol is called.


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ol2JbwoJp0